# Syntax Error: Passing multiple variables with php and mysql (Shopping Cart)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently having a problem with a syntax error on my shopping cart application. What I am trying to do is when a user clicks add to cart is to pass multiple variables to my cart page and add it to a table.

Here is the syntax error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'item = 'Test Product 1' quantity = '4' price ='1' total = '4'' at line 1"

Line of code where syntax error occurs:

```
echo '<td><a href="http://localhost/websiteryanbakelaar/Content/add-to-cart.php?id='. $row['id'] . '&item=' . $row['itemname'] . '&quantity=' . $row['quantity'] . '&price=' . $row['price'] . '&total=' . $row['total'] . '">Add to Cart</a></td>';
```

Im a bit new to php, so any tips would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use quote (') for your parameters other then string data types.

Comment: Did you realize that error comes from MySQL syntax error, not from PHP syntax error? This line seems ok. Show us more code.

Comment: You are missing a `comma` between all columns either in `update` or `insert` command.

Comment: Ill post some more code in a second here.

Comment: `$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mycart SET id = '$id' item = '$item' quantity = '$quantity' price ='$price' total = '$total'") or die (mysql_error());
` Here is my database insert.

Comment: I fixed the problem thanks to Ravinder. I feel like an idiot haha. I didn't know you needed to use commas when passing the parameters. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have posted your `insert` query into it doesn't seems to be `insert` query you were mixing `insert` and `update` query

**INSERT query**

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

and **UPDATE query**

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value `enter code here`
```

If you want to insert data then your query must be like this..

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mycart (id,item,quantity,price,total) values ('$id','$item','$quantity','$price','$total')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thank you that seemed to fix my problem before. Ravinder fixed my problem but since he didn't post his comment as an answer i'll mark this as best.